# Sitecore query/fast query for user

Tags: sitecore

Is there a way to use fast query or query to get a user by email or a custom field? I tried this but it didn't work in the Query Tool

/sitecore/user//*[@@templateid='{642C9A7E-EE31-4979-86F0-39F338C10AFB}' AND @email='abc@123.com']

Comment: When you say "user," do you mean actual Sitecore users that you get to via the User Manager, stored in the Core DB, or do you mean a custom template you've created in a new part of the tree (`/sitecore/user`)?

Comment: I mean sitecore users can be accessed using the User Manager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot query (via Sitecore Query or Fast Query) users in the User Manager because they are not items, they're actually built on ASP.NET Membership in the Core database. Instead, you can look into something like `Membership.GetAllUsers()` ([MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx)) and filter the results with LINQ based on what you're looking for.

I've done something similar in Sitecore where I called `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserManager.GetUsers()` and filtered the resulting `User` objects by their name property. You could do something similar like this:

```
var matches = UserManager.GetUsers().Where(usr => usr.Profile.Email.Equals(emailToMatch));
```