# Sitecore 6 export user list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there a repeatable way to export a list of users from the user manager. I've been through the 6.2 docs and online with no success.

Comment: Is this something you need to do programmatically?

Comment: Ideally it would be a user function, like the export feature in web forms for marketers. Looks like we'll have to roll something up.

Comment: For that, you would need to create a new application or function in Sitecore using some of the code samples provided below as answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore's user management is built on ASP.NET membership, so you can use the standard ASP.NET classes to access users. The question "[Sitecore query/fast query for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579247/sitecore-query-fast-query-for-user/8581423)" might help a bit.

Here's some sample code to get you started:

```
var users = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserManager.GetUsers();
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest/quickest way I've found is to use the user manager's serialization function. I think you've been able to do it since v6. Here's the [documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/serialization_guide_sc60-64-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain class has a GetUsers() method, if you need to conveniently list only the users in a specific security domain.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue, and used Mark's suggestion. Heres my (hacked together) code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        var users = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserManager.GetUsers();
        foreach (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User item in users)
        {
            string email = "";
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Profile.Email) ){
                email = item.Profile.Email;
            }
            output.AppendFormat("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>",
                    item.DisplayName.ToString(),
                    email,
                    item.Profile.Comment
                  );
        }
        showusers.Text = output.ToString();
    }
```

Notice that the default sitecore user fields make it in there, they're just in `.Profile`