# Sitecore - Possible to personalize content items in tree?

Tags: sitecore, personalization

I know that it's possible to personalize components. Is there also a way to personalize content items that are located in the Sitecore tree in a similar way?

Comment: What would you be personalizing? The content that goes into a field? That's not how personization works with Sitecore. Personalization with Sitecore is primarily, using the Rules Engine to provide Sitecore conditions for it to evaluate and determine the best fit for the visitor, the user, the component, etc... Along with that, you define which datasource Sitecore should use once a given a condition is evaluated to true.

Comment: I have a component with an item as datasource. It displays that item's children (approx. 200 items). I want the editors to be able to set up, which role can(not) see some of those items. I know it can be done by assigning access rights to the items in a role, but editors wouldn't be able to do it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Users and roles cannot be queried in sitecore since they are not items (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579247/sitecore-query-fast-query-for-user), same goes for roles).

Unfortunately (?) you cannot grant write access to the *__Security* field via the Security Editor. You could create a custom field type that queries the roles.

If you actually want to **set** the access rights, you could create a processor in the *saveUI* pipeline that transfers the data of your field into the *__Security* field (you need to use *SecurityDisabler*). Use the framework functionality if possible so you don't have to construct the access rights string yourself.